# How can I change the value of $ProjectFileDir$ in IntelliJ IDEA 13?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I've added an item to my Tools menu using the XML below that runs custom actions for my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolSet name="My Project Utilities">
    <tool name="test" showInMainMenu="true" showInEditor="true" showInProject="true" showInSearchPopup="true" disabled="false" useConsole="true" showConsoleOnStdOut="false" showConsoleOnStdErr="false" synchronizeAfterRun="false">
        <exec>
            <option name="COMMAND" value="C:\path\to\ant.bat" />
            <option name="PARAMETERS" value="my_task -Dmodule.dir=$ProjectFileDir$\my.module" />
            <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$ProjectFileDir$/my.working.dir/foo" />
        </exec>
    </tool>
</toolSet>
```

When I try to run this task, I get this error:

```
Error running test:
Cannot start process, the working directory C:\projects\something\my.working.dir\foo does not exist
```

The problem is `$ProjectFileDir$` points to the wrong directory, `C:\projects\something`, and I need it to point to `C:\projects`. Is there a way to change the value of `$ProjectFileDir` without modifying the value of `WORKING_DIRECTORY` in my XML?

Answer (score -1):

we did the samething but with a batch file . uploading the batch file and adding the project path at working directory .

Go to File >> Settings >> External Tools >> Add (+) Create Tool , you can follow the image. Hope this helps.

[image]